# Blurring background in only a select area (behind text)

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm creating a homepage using HTML/CSS/Javascript, on this page I have text floating on the top left portion of the screen. I have a number of backgrounds saved from Reddit and a script which randomly selects one upon start, my problem is that because this background can be any colour it is difficult for the text to be readable, so my idea was to blur the background around just the text in order to make it readable. Ideally, it would follow just the text and blur the outline of it but I tried placing it in a box, however, because it uses relative layout it was difficult to have the box fill and blur the minimum space possible.

How can I improve the readability of text by blurring the background just around the text? I'm also open to other suggestions to improve readability (remembering the background changes)

Comment: Folks here may be able to answer your question re: blurring a background, but for design questions consider other Stack Exchange sites like [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/). You may get pushback about this question not being suited for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the CSS3 filters: https://www.inserthtml.com/2012/06/css-filters/

The link above should have a guide on how to blur image and you should be able to modify this to fit your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It's a quick n dirty fix... but I usually just add a contrast background color to the text wrapper (like the first one in the example below). You can also use blur filter if you want. I referred to this article [frosting glass css filter](https://css-tricks.com/frosting-glass-css-filters/) for the second one. But in the comment of that article, some say there's a trade off of performance.

```css
#bg {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/500/400?image=0) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#text-wrap1 {
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px white;
  width: 150px;
}

#text-wrap2 {
  padding: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
}
#text-wrap2 p {
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px white;
}
#text-wrap2:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  -webkit-filter: url('#blur');
  filter: url('#blur');
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="bg">
    <div id="text-wrap1">
      This is a random paragraph
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="bg">
    <div id="text-wrap2">
      <p>This is a random paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have chosen the difficult way. Simply use CSS `text-shadow` Property. For example if the text is in black, use white shadow color for it.

**Example:**

```css
body {
    background-image: url('https://images.template.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/01191816/Perfect-Summer-Background-Free-Download.png');
    background-size: cover
}
.text {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 10px #fff
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Some Text</div>
```